# Magento admin products showing error

Tags: product, catalog, products, call

**When I click on CATALOG>PRODUCTS then It's showing me the following message:**

[image: products]

> **How can I solve this?**

Comment: which things you have do recently?

Comment: I was deleting all products . It was continuously  running then I closed that tab and the opened again this happened

Comment: Have you try to clear browser cache or check into another tab?

Comment: After compile upgrade and deploy It's gone now

Comment: Yes, the issues something that one.

Comment: This issues is xml problem.So you are any change any xml file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the following commands and check.

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile

php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

sudo chmod -R 777 var/ generated/ pub/
```

Comment: The problem is still there !